# I bought DLC pack 1 and 2, but it says I've only pre-ordered and can't even play DLC pack 1

Tags: mario-kart-8

I just purchased DLC packs 1 and 2.  I know that pack 2 doesn't release until May 2015, but pack 1 with Link should already be out.  When we go to select Link or one of the other new characters, it brings up a screen saying that I only pre-ordered and won't let me start the race.  Do I need to do something special here?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my own issue by turning off the Wii U (probably could have just exited the game) and then starting the game again.  It then went through an update, after which the three characters were available for play.

Comment: Ah, the classic _"have you tried turning it off and on again?"_